# Select xml element matching attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have following xml content :

```xml
<root>
    <content>
        <figure id="fig-001">
            <graphic id="fig-001-graId-001"/>
            <graphic id="fig-001-graId-002"/>
            <graphic id="fig-001-graId-003"/>
        </figure>
        <figure id="fig-002">
            <graphic id="fig-002-graId-001"/>
            <graphic id="fig-002-graId-002"/>
        </figure>        
        <refs>
            <ref ref-id="fig-001-graId-001" type="test"/>
            <ref ref-id="fig-002-graId-001" type="test"/>
        </refs>
    </content>
</root>
```

I use oXygen

I click on an element refs/ref, for example on

```
<ref ref-id="fig-01-graId-001 type="test" />
```

I want an xpath which count 'graphic' element in figure having graphic/@id=ref/@ref-id (whene i clicked), something like that :

count(//content/figure/graphic[@id=//ref/@ref-id]/parent::/graphic) ==> 3 (parent of graphic with ref-id=fig-001-graId-001 have 3 graphic elements)

Comment: Which result do you want to have for that input sample?

Comment: I edited my question, Sorry, It wasn't correct

Comment: "*I click on an element refs/ref*" XPath does not know where you clicked.

Comment: @Valeriane It makes no difference. XPath still does not know where you clicked. If you want this to work as described, you need to have your parent application pass the selected node as a variable to XPath - if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically mentioned oXygen, so here's one option:

```
for $refid in @ref-id return count(//figure[graphic/@id = $refid]/graphic)
```

This XPath 2.0 would need to be used in the XPath Toolbar (be sure you have XPath 2.0 selected). I don't think you can use the XPath builder because you lose your context.

The only time I could get this to work correctly 100% of the time is to make sure when I clicked on the `ref` element, the 2 brackets under the start and end of the element were present (after clicking in the XPath Toolbar to run the XPath). This ensures that the context is correct. (This can be done by clicking directly after `<ref`.)

The brackets are highlighted in the screenshot below. Also notice the correct results at the bottom of the screenshot:

[image]

**Update:** Adding `ancestor-or-self::*[1]` seems to help with getting the correct context no matter where in the element you click:

```
for $refid in ancestor-or-self::*[1]/@ref-id return count(//figure[graphic/@id = $refid]/graphic)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

```
count(//graphic[@id=//ref/@ref-id]/../graphic)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
count(//figure[graphic/@id=//ref/@ref-id]/graphic)
```

Comment: @Valeriane Please explain what you mean. There is only one ref/@ref-id in your input example. If there were two (or more), both would be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

With a key you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:key name="id" match="figure" use="graphic/@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="count(key('id', //ref/@ref-id)/graphic)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

see http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGc1

Comment: thank you for your response. Unfortunately I can't use xsl

Comment: Then consider to remove the xslt tag.